# How Do I Download Test Step Attachments for Test Cases in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to download all the test step attachments for a test case through API Call using `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`.

My call works but where do I find the attachment in my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How Do I Download Test Step Attachments for Test Cases in Azure DevOps

That because the REST API [Attachments - Get Test Result Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get%20test%20result%20attachment%20zip?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
will display the context of the attachments instead of download the attachments directly.

To resolve this issue, we could save the attachment to the file by the scripts like:

```
$AttachmentsOutfile = "D:\Testcase\AttachmentsOutfile.trx"

$connectionToken="You PAT Here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::  
ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$AuditLogURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

$AuditInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuditLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $AttachmentsOutfile
```

The test result:

[image]